# Inconsistency with Different sized phones

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have come across a problem with the consistency of the layout of my login across different sized phones. There's one screenshot with a Samsung S9 and another with an S10+, the S9 is completely fine but the S10+ isn't as you'll see in the screenshots below:

https://gyazo.com/b9d2b599dc1a7ecf0a3c5d0e7a72032c (Correct Layout) 
https://gyazo.com/b16a2504925e59529548ed4ce85d15f7 (Incorrect Layout)

In the incorrect one, the email and password is a little too high than what it should be at, although it isnt by much its still getting in the way of the logo.

I've tried research on google but didn't find anything useful about the problem/

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Cabiee;assembly=Cabiee"
         BackgroundImage="CabieBackground.jpg"
         x:Class="Cabiee.Login">

<ContentPage.Content>

    <Grid Margin="20,0,20,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height = "150"/>
            <RowDefinition Height = "50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height = "50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height = "50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height = "50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height = "50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height = "*"/>

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width = "5"/>

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackLayout  Grid.Row = "2" Grid.Column="1" Orientation = "Horizontal" WidthRequest="300" > 
            <Image 
                Source="baseline_email_black_18"/>
            <Entry 
                x:Name="usernameEntry" 
                Placeholder="Email"
                WidthRequest="300"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout  Grid.Row = "3" Grid.Column="1" Orientation = "Horizontal" WidthRequest="300" >
            <Image Source="baseline_https_black_18" />
            <Entry 
                x:Name="passwordEntry"
                IsPassword="true"
                 Placeholder="*********"
                Completed="PasswordEntry_Completed"
                 WidthRequest="300"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <Button  
                x:Name="BtnLogin"
                HeightRequest="50"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                WidthRequest="300"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Grid.Row="4"
                Clicked="BtnLogin_Clicked"
                Text="Login"
                TextColor="White"
                FontSize="20"
                CornerRadius="20"
                BackgroundColor="Black"/>

        <Button
            x:Name="ForgotPassword"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            Text="Forgot your Password?" 
            Grid.Column="1" 
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Grid.Row="5"
            WidthRequest="300"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        <!--TextColor="Blue" -->

        <Button       
                    x:Name="BtnRegister"
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    Text="Don't have an Account? Register here"
                    Clicked="BtnRegister_Clicked"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Grid.Row="6"
                    WidthRequest="300"
                    VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"

                    FontAttributes="None"
                     />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

I expect the final outcome to be the same across all phones but obviously, there is something wrong in the code.

Thanks!

Comment: Its not about entry shifting towards top, but looks like your image stretched out and shifted to bottom, can you please share code with top image as well?

Comment: It's the same code for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with the below code, this might solve your problem and see screenshot attached.

```
<Grid Margin="20,0,20,0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="150" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" /> 
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalOptions="Fill" >
                    <Image Source="bsg_icn_title2.jpg" />
                    <Entry x:Name="usernameEntry" Placeholder="Email"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="3"  Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
                    <Image Source="bsg_icn_title2.jpg" />
                    <Entry x:Name="passwordEntry" IsPassword="true" Placeholder="*********" Completed="PasswordEntry_Completed" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                </StackLayout>

                <Button x:Name="BtnLogin" HeightRequest="50" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="300" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="4" Clicked="BtnLogin_Clicked" Text="Login" TextColor="White"
                    FontSize="20" CornerRadius="20" BackgroundColor="Black" />
                <Button x:Name="ForgotPassword" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Text="Forgot your Password?" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="5" WidthRequest="300" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

                <!--TextColor="Blue" -->
                <Button x:Name="BtnRegister" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Text="Don't have an Account? Register here" Clicked="BtnRegister_Clicked"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="6" WidthRequest="300" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    FontAttributes="None" />

            </Grid>
```

[image: Check screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

From ScreenShot image , does not seem to correspond to the code of xaml.

If using `Grid` in xaml.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid#placing-views-in-a-grid

> Note that Grid.Row and Grid.Column specify location based on the zero-based lists of rows and columns. This means that in a 4x4 grid, the top left cell is (0,0) and the bottom right cell is (3,3).

However , your code is from 1 to set in xaml.

And you can set [RowSpacing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid#spacing) to check whether can solve this.

eg:`<Grid x:Name="controlGrid" RowSpacing="1">`

Comment: Do you mean my Grid.Column starts from 1?

Comment: @Cbrady No,`Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` all should start from 0. eg: If have 5 Row, should start from 0, and end in 4.Not staring from 1 or 2.